# Limit number of requests sent per IP on Google App Engine Flex?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, nginx, google-cloud-platform, rate-limiting

I am trying to add limit requests per IP on `Google App Engine` **FLex** NodeJs, I saw this [rate-limiting-nginx](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/) documentation where Rate Limiting is applied on Nginx, but how can I use it inside my App Engine app.

Also is there any default setting or any other way for rate limiting on Google App Engine?

Answer (score -2):

*To use the rate limiting feature, configure _quota metrics_ and _quota limits_ in the service configuration for your service producer project.*

You can read it in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/rate-limiting#enforcing_rate_limiting)